# Writing a file after umbrella app initialization Elixir/Phoenix, for Nginx initialization in Heroku

Tags: nginx, heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an umbrella application in elixir with two app endpoints, one for API, and another one for IoT. I am using a reverse proxy to serve the application as there are two endpoints running on different ports.

The build pack being used for the reverse proxy is:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx

This is my Nginx configuration file.

```
daemon off;
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
 use epoll;
 accept_mutex on;
 worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

server_tokens off;

log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
sendfile on;

#Must read the body in 5 seconds.
client_body_timeout 5;

upstream api {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=60s;
}

upstream iot {
    server 127.0.0.1:4001 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=60s;
}

server {
    listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /api {
        allow all;

        # Proxy Headers
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;

        # The Important Websocket Bits!
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://api;

    }

    location /iot {
        allow all;

        # Proxy Headers
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;

        # The Important Websocket Bits!
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://iot;

    }
}
```

}

Apparently, the buildpack expects a file `/tmp/app-initialized` to be [written once the app is initialized](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx#applicationdyno-coordination).

The command I am using is `mix phx.server` to start the umbrella. 
What would be the right way to write this file(`/tmp/app-initialized`) after app initialization in the phoenix umbrella.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the `phx.server` task [phx.server.ex](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.4.11/lib/mix/tasks/phx.server.ex#L1)

You can slightly change that and create your own task that does the same plus writing the file:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Bootstrap do
  use Mix.Task

  def run(_) do
    Application.put_env(:phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true, persistent: true)
    case Application.ensure_all_started(:the_name_of_your_app) do
       {:ok, _} ->
            ####
            #### write the file
            ####
            Mix.Tasks.Run.run run_args() ++ ["--no-start"]
       _error -> raise "Unable to start..."
    end
  end

  defp run_args do
    if iex_running?(), do: [], else: ["--no-halt"]
  end

  defp iex_running? do
    Code.ensure_loaded?(IEx) and IEx.started?
  end

end
```

You just need to drop this new file into somewhere in `lib` and then pass the command as `mix bootstrap` instead of `mix phx.server`.

Given how applications & (?) components (?) are started in erlang&elixir, you could also have a simple `gen_server` as part of your application supervision tree, after the endpoints have been initialised, that does that writing.

```
defmodule Server.Application do

  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      ServerWeb.Endpoint,
      ServerIOT.Endpoint,
      Supervisor.child_spec(%{id: Server.Liveness, start: {Server.Liveness, :start_link, []}}, type: :worker)
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Server.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  # Tell Phoenix to update the endpoint configuration
  # whenever the application is updated.
  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    ServerWeb.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

Obviously changing the names for your case. The `Server.Liveness` could simply be a transient gen_server, that only does that, write the file on start and exiting normally afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this one out.

Comment: I was able to make a few changes and use this script. One important step was to move ` Mix.Tasks.Run.run run_args() ++ ["--no-start"]` outside the case statement as without it all the apps in umbrella won't start working. Maybe, if you edit that, I will mark this as the answer.